# select a string from sql server with slash it include a backslash

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a data in my sql server like this

http://172.xx.xx.xx/Lesson1Makeview.pdf

my query is like this :

```
select mag_link from [_DB].[dbo].[magazine_details]
```

then when i put to json i've got

```
http:\/\/172.16.11.29:7777\/Lesson1Makeview.pdf
```

there's a \ in the link i've got.

how will i remove it?

im using c#

Comment: Where is your code? why is it tagged with JSON?

Comment: First of all ow is this related to json? You've shown no C# code and only your sql query. Does it return as a string? Then you could use string.Replace("\", "") Why is it stored with \ in the first place? I downvoted your question, because it's too unclear what you really want to do and it seems like you have no idea what you're even doing.

Comment: "then when I put to json i've got"; ok; what tool or code did you use to "put to json"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an entirely valid representation in JSON; it is *unnecessary* to escape `/` as `\/`, but it is *valid* to do so.

If you don't want to perform an *unnecessary* escape, then: use a tool that doesn't do that. JSON.NET does not add this, for example:

```
var obj = new Foo { url = "http://foo.com" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Which results in the string:

```
{"url":"http://foo.com"}
```

However, both the json above and the json below will deserialize to mean the same thing

```
{"url":"http:\/\/foo.com"}
```